# Can you access @Autowire'd fields through static references?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

Let's say you have the following setup:

```
public class Producer {

    public Product produce() { /* Creates some product */ }
}

@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private Producer producer;

    public Product produce() { producer.produce(); }
}

public class Factory {

    private static ProductService productService = new ProductService();

    public static Product produce() { productService.produce(); }
}
```

When I call `Factory.produce()`, I get a `NullPointerException`, because `producer` is null. Since `producer` itself is not a static field, I was hoping that by setting it up this way, I could use Springs dependency injection in a static context. Did I make a mistake, or is this simply not possible?

For context: In my real application, `Factory` holds multiple services, which in turn each hold multiple producers. I chose this structure so the rest of my application only needs to access the `Factory`, with all of the complexity behind it being abstracted by it.

Comment: is the productService in the class Factory injected properly? Or did you just not put it?

Comment: @jorrin Forgot the constructor. Since it is a static reference, it can't be injected. Which is the core issue that I'm trying to get around by doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just annotate the constuctor of `Factory` with `@Autowired`

```
@Component
public class Factory {

    private static ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    public Factory(ProductService productService) {
        Factory.productService = productService;
    }

    public static Product produce() { productService.produce(); }
}
```